# C# text box values from SQL server as typing

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a C# application to user for my brother in his store.

I have a SQL Server database that stores all sold items, The items are added from the application.

When the user enters text in the 'CustomerName' field in the application, i want it to do a DB call and check for any previous sales with the same customer name (or what has been typed of the name so far) and fill in the text box will the name.

The problem i am having is: if there is a customer called John and another called Joe and i need to select John, if i type in J in the box, it will just select Joe, and then return the text cursor to the beginning of the text box which is rather annoying and inconvenient.

The ideal solution would be is if i type J in the textbox, a dropdown box just below the text box would appear displaying all the Customers with J, allowing the user to select a customer and then filling in the textbox with the value. If i then type Jo, all the records for Jo would appear in the dropdown etc.

The coding part shouldn't be a problem (hopefully), i just wanted to know the best way to approach this.

Comment: Search for [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx) and [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) property

Comment: C# application ? Forms, Silverlight, asp.net, mvc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add/change these properties in your textbox

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

then you could use this method to get a List of customer names that start with your prefix.

```
public List<string> GetCustomerInfo(string custName)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string sql = "Select Name from Customers Where Name like @partName";
    using(SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
         con.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partName", custName + "%"); 
         using(SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while(r.Read()) 
              {
                  if(!r.IsDbNull(0)) 
                      result.Add(r.GetString(0)); 
              }
         }
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

As a safeguard I will check if the text typed in your combobox is at least three chars

```
if(textBox1.Text.Length >= 3)
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = GetCustomerInfo(textBox1.Text);
else
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = null;
```

Comment: -1, if for anything then for the fact that you just HAD to use paramters instead of making a SQL Injection attack ;) -1 for using a DataTable that makes little sense here. So neutral.

Comment: @TomTom your comment has merit, in my defense I can only say that I was in a rush. Updated the answer with some optimizations.

Comment: my comment actually was +1 and -1. not what the -1 is fixed ;) The +1 is on ;) Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use jQuery to make an AJAX call to a server side function to do the lookup for you.

**Consider this C#**:

```
public string getNames(string prefix)
{
     //logic to perform your name retrieval from the SQL Server database based on the passed in string parameter: "prefix"
     return "John,Joe,Joseph";
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //assign the getNames() function each time the key is 
    //pressed on the txtNames input
    $('#txtName').keyup(function(){
        getNames();
    });
});

function getNames(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page-to-post-to.ashx',
        data: {
            prefix: 'J'
        },
        success: function(data){
            //data will return : 'John,Joe,Joseph'
            //use your javascript logic to separate these names by the comma delimiter
            //and use them!
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input id="txtName" />
```

This may not be 100% correct, but it should at least get you started down the right path.

Comment: I should mention that the C# function `getNames(string prefix)` resides in the `page-to-post-to.ashx` file that I mentioned in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set these properties of your textbox or write them to your form :

```
yourTextbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
yourTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

and then you can create an instance of an ArrayList, a String array or a List (or a dictonary if you will need ID of the customer name) as you prefer..

or just you can use `AutoCompleteStringCollection` -it is also an implemented string array/collection in C#- class instance to retrieve data into..

then set `txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = yourListOfTheMatchedNames;`

a small example to give you an idea:

```
void yourTextBox_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlDataReader dReader;
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = strConnection;
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //better is to use a stored proc or if you use a .NET 3.5 or higher framework then LinqtoSQL
   cmd.CommandText = "Select [yourNameColumn] from yourNameTable where yourNameColumn LIKE" + yourTextBox.Text +"%"; //before lines from this you can set them initializing code part of your form..it will be your choice
   conn.Open();
   dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (dReader.HasRows == true)
   {
       yourListOfTheMatchedNames.Clear(); // to clear previous search..its optional to depends of your choice
       while (dReader.Read())
       {                  
              yourListOfTheMatchedNames.Add(dReader["Name"].ToString());    
       }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is No Customer Name Starts with You Typed");
    }
    dReader.Close();

    txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = yourListOfTheMatchedNames;

}
```

Comment: -1, if for anything then for the fact that ou just HAD to give a very bad example for using SQL and create a SQL Injection opportunity, where a parameter use would have been easier. +1 for using a DataReader, so neutral ;)

Comment: Bte., the check for HasRows is redundant - you can just use Read (). You KNOW that a result set will be returned as the SQL always does so. Also you should use USING in case an excptoion occurs - also makes the close smaller (no close).

Comment: Thank you very much everybody :) makes sense now.

Comment: i attempted this approach and it worked :) however when i close the database connection, the dropdown dissappears :( it there any way to fix it?

Comment: @TomTom exactly You are right and thank you for the useful comment..That's the only reason why i wrote a comment in code as "better is storedproc" ;)

and..I tried to give step by step..Otherway i always use dbcreate(config) function within a DAAB ;)

i wrote hasrows check cause of giving an idea about how and where can check..exactly using db activities in bracelets of "using" is the best option when we understand the logic ;) there, i tried to show how can we check db activity (data reading) as an example..

again thank you to give us (specially for exact beginners)  useful knowledge

Comment: @user1431743 i guess you forgot to take the retrieved data into a list or array.. did you do this ?